# Jquery.Click() Doens't work after it's used one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a really simple jquery.Click() function

```
//hide divs
$("#a-1").hide();

$(".v-1").click(function(){
    $("#a-1").show();
    $(".v-1").addClass("c-it");
    $(".c-it").click(function(){
        $("#a-1").hide();
        $(".v-1").removeClass("c-it");
    });
});
```

So when v-1 is clicked a-1 has to show and it will add an class named c-it. That works after that i click c-it , a-1 will hide again and the c-it class will be removed. So now we are the beginning again but now when i click v-1 nothing happens someone knows why?

Html

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus v-1">&nbsp;<span>This is a question</span></i>
        <div id="a-1"><p>Awnser</p></div>
```

Comment: you must have click on only <i element only and when you click on a-1 it is hole div covers

Comment: After you attach the second click handler, both handlers execute upon a click of `.v-1`. You can test that by adding an `alert()` in each of them. You need to handle the logic in a single handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) better for you

```
$("#a-1").hide();

$(".v-1").click(function() {
  $("#a-1").toggle('hide');
  $(".v-1").toggleClass("c-it");

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a single click handler that simply toggles the visible state and the class.

```
$(".v-1").click(function(){
    $("#a-1").toggle();
    $(".v-1").toggleClass("c-it");
});
```